# Pagination control in blackberry 10

Tags: blackberry-10

Hi I am developing an application that will display pages in horizontal view. When if user swipes his finger on the current page it moves to next or previous page according to the finger movement direction. it should be like Pagination view in Android, not Scrollview. Can be it possible in Blackberry 10.

Answer (score 0):

I could be flippant and say yes it can be done, cite as evidence the built in Twitter and Picture viewing applications, and ask for the 50 points. I will instead just point out stackoverflow is a programing assistance site. You have only presented a set of specifications, not what you have looked at or tried or even what you will be paging through.

The ListView class can be configured to display enormous amounts of data efficiently by recycling the display object as the user moves the viewpoint around the list. The subclasses of ListLayout provide ways to modify how data is presented on the list. I sugest you look at StackListLayout, its orientation property and Listview, its snapMode property.

Since you did not indicate what you are scrolling through I can't recommend a DataModel.

Comment: I am looking for some thing that is similar to Android's ViewPager.